# Ajax History API default content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I currently use a small Javascript-based code, for my Ajax pages, etc. but I'm stuck at one important step; the default content. I've tried to just write content in the `#content` div.. It seemed to work, even with the Ajax page-push (That it would disappear after a content changed.) But once I reload the page, it is back again.

So, does anyone know how to display default content, without it appearing after a page refresh (If the content changed)?

**CODE:**

```
$(function () {
    var load = function (url) {
        $.get(url).done(function (data) {
            $("#content").html(data);
        })
    };

    $(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this),
            url = $this.attr("href"),
            title = $this.text();

        history.pushState({
            url: url,
            title: title
        }, title, url);

        document.title = title;

        load(url);
    });

    $(window).on('popstate', function (e) {
        var state = e.originalEvent.state;
        if (state !== null) {
            document.title = state.title;
            load(state.url);
        } else {
            document.title = 'World Regions';
            $("#content").empty();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is back again after you reload the page?

Comment: @MichaelMontero The default text that I entered, inside of the ```#content``` div. That particular text should be gone, because there is other content loaded (So, you'll see two pages of content, instead of one).